# Jquery recent issue: whatever url is request I have an "unrecognized expression"

Tags: jquery

I was off my siteweb project for a while (means almost 2 months) and now when I'm working on it, if I do a preserve log on my console I often see this: `unrecognized expression`

When I click to "add a profile" for the example, the error is still showing:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized >expression: /en/admin/djangocms_partner_profile/profilepartner/add/

And the add profile, or what ever admin / front stuff I click on now has this error.

Any idea about it?

Many thanks!

Edit: Jquery version 1.11.3

Comment: 500 is a server error, so its nothing to do with jquery, you should check your django logging

Comment: Shouldn't I be having a 500 from my js as well then?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the 500 is the response's status for your request.

Comment: There is no such type issue with jquery. There may be js files confliction

Comment: Ok I will look for it, thank you Deepak